# Rank of two-pair hands for low in razz or 7-stud hi-low

Tags: rules, seven-card-stud

Which hand would be ranked the lowest at razz or 7-card hi-low,

two pairs of 2's and 9's, or two pairs of 4's and 5's    ??

Answer (score 2):

To see which hand is higher, you always start with the highest pair first, and then consider the lower pair only if the highest pair is the same.

In this example, the pair of 9's beats the pair of 5's and is the higher (losing in this case) hand, and the second pair doesn't matter (other than the fact that it makes it two pair).

If it were 99 22 -vs- 99 44 then you would consider the bottom pair and the 4's would make the second example the higher hand.

Comment: I would suggest using the terms better/worse when dealing with hi-low games. using highest might be a little confusing

Comment: @amigal: Well, I think that better and worse are even more ambiguous than high/low.  A hand is *always* higher or lower, but that can be better or worse, depending on the game that you are playing.  It's just that a high hand isn't a good thing in low games.  :)

Comment: @Inafziger: maybe we should combine and use "best low hand" and best high hand"....

Answer (score 0):

In `Razz` or `7-Stud Hi-Lo`, you have 7 cards and you must take 5 cards to make your hand. If you have 2 pairs, you have 3 other differents cards. You must take them in order to have no pairs in your hand.

For example, if you have A2299TK, your hand will be A29TK. It's a `K Higher`.

In a hand like 224499J (3 pairs in 7 cards), your final hand will have a `Pair` (2249J).

Now, comparing 2 `Highers` is not difficult, as you compare starting higher card (K->Q->J->T->9->8 ...)

Be carefull in `Hi-Lo games`, there is not always a `Low`. Every card higher than `8` can't be used to make a `Low Hand`.

Comment: In the rules I've seen, a low hand contain any pairs, but may contain any rank of card; if a game is described as 2-7 low, that means that aces are considered high and straights (and presumably flushes) are ineligible to be considered "low" hands; so the lowest hand would be 2-3-4-5-7; in an A-5 low game, aces count as low, and straights are eligible to be low hands, so A-2-3-4-5 is the lowest hand with no pair.